# Resizing the size of a div container based on the size of the browser when there is a footer under it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been making a website out of boredom, and on the homepage (and eventually there will be on every page) there is a footer, just like the one on stackoverflow, and on the homepage there is a header, a section of text at the top, the main part, and the footer. I want the main div to expand when you resize the page, and the minimum height being 500px.

The code I have tried so far:

```
.tutorials {
    background: linear-gradient( 180deg, rgb(240,230,220), rgb(200,190,180) );
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 66%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
```

Even though this code resizes the main div, the footer text will not move down while the main div expands, which blocks the footer text. Also, if I make the page smaller than the minimum height and then scroll down, instead of the main div being 500px and the footer being below it, as I scroll the top of the div stays in a fixed place and makes an empty white space between the top text and the main div. As I keep scrolling down, instead of showing the footer this gap above it gets further. Adding the code position: fixed does not help in any way. I would prefer to use either HTML, CSS or jQuery to fix this, but I am open to other languages if necessary.

Comment: You will need to share more code with us if you want help.

Comment: Please, create a plunker or codepen for our experiments, there will be much easier to find right solution

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive on your exact situation, but I believe I can help. I interpreted your question to mean that you want the main div to expand and the footer to stay below it. You can set the position of the footer to relative (`position: relative;`) and then use `clear: both;` to make sure it doesn't ride up on any divs above it. Here's an example of it in action:

```css
#main{
  width: 70%;
  height: 20vw;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange; 
  min-height: 150px;
}

#side{
  width: 30%;
  height: 20vw;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 150px;
}

#footer{
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
     <div id="main"><h1>Main</h1></div>
     <div id="side"><h1>Side</h1></div>
     <div id="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div>
   </body>
</html>
```